# В Django на продакшене при добалении позиции в админке выходит ошибка 404

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, веб-сервер, django-admin

Разработал сайт локально, там всё работает. Но на продакшене через админ-панель при добавлении новой позиции выходит - Page not found (404). Нагуглил, что проблема скорее всего с полями Image, но не нашёл, как пофиксить. Подозреваю, что проблема в путях BASE_DIR и MEDIA_ROOT

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pharmacy.urls')),
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls', namespace='articles')),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

В самом приложении:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='main'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

Модель:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Название')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, verbose_name='Описание', blank=True, null=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Картинка', upload_to='pharmacy/products')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Опубликовано', default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Продукт'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты'
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "pharmacy/static",
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Прикладываю скрин со структурой файлов. Переносил на сервер не я.[image: Скрин файловой структуры]

Добавлю больше информации: Я получаю следующее сообщение -
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://example/admin/pharmacy/review/add/
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view

Comment: Кто и где конкретно выдаёт ошибку 404?

Comment: @andreymal браузер выводит страницу 404, через консоль - то же самое - mysite/articles/article/add - page not found.

Using the URLconf defined in pharma.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='main']
about [name='about']
contact [name='contact']
articles/ [name='articles']
articles/ article/<int:pk> [name='article']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, articles/article/add/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: А где потерялось слово admin в адресе?

Comment: @andreymal , сорри, да, потерял - mysite/admin/articles/article/add/

Comment: @andreymal , это я просто забыл здесь написать, оно всё равно не работает.